# In DDD, why don't you use arrays to store collections of entities?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I've seen in all DDD examples, collections are implemented as classes, for example at PHPMaster website:

```
<?php
namespace Model\Collection;
use Mapper\UserCollectionInterface,
    Model\UserInterface;

class UserCollection implements UserCollectionInterface
{
    protected $users = array();

    public function add(UserInterface $user) {
        $this->offsetSet($user);
    }

    public function remove(UserInterface $user) {
        $this->offsetUnset($user);
    }

    public function get($key) {
        return $this->offsetGet($key);
    }

    public function exists($key) {
        return $this->offsetExists($key);
    }

    public function clear() {
        $this->users = array();
    }

    public function toArray() {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function count() {
        return count($this->users);
    }

    public function offsetSet($key, $value) {
        if (!$value instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                "Could not add the user to the collection.");
        }
        if (!isset($key)) {
            $this->users[] = $value;
        }
        else {
            $this->users[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetUnset($key) {
        if ($key instanceof UserInterface) {
            $this->users = array_filter($this->users,
                function ($v) use ($key) {
                    return $v !== $key;
                });
        }
        else if (isset($this->users[$key])) {
            unset($this->users[$key]);
        }
    }

    public function offsetGet($key) {
        if (isset($this->users[$key])) {
            return $this->users[$key];
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($key) {
        return ($key instanceof UserInterface)
            ? array_search($key, $this->users)
            : isset($this->users[$key]);
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new \ArrayIterator($this->users);
    }
}
```

And the interface:

```
<?php
namespace Mapper;
use Model\UserInterface;

interface UserCollectionInterface extends \Countable, \ArrayAccess, \IteratorAggregate 
{
    public function add(UserInterface $user);
    public function remove(UserInterface $user);
    public function get($key);
    public function exists($key);
    public function clear();
    public function toArray();
}
```

Why don't they just use a simple array? What benefits do you get by using a given implementation?

Comment: This question might be better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com (a "what goes on the whiteboard" vs "what gets typed into code" kind of question)

Comment: DDD says nothing about using arrays.

Comment: The idea is that you can change the implementation at any time, without affecting the code. So for a (bad) example, say they had a limited amount of memory and needed to store the user collection on disk, it would be very simple to change.

Comment: Why use classes at all, when you can use arrays and functions for everything?

Comment: @meze  cannot extend functions. when classes are written correctly reusing code and tweaking the outcome to suite your needs becomes very easy, and done very quickly.

Comment: Although applied to DDD in your example it also relates to dependency inversion which is a good principle to follow when possible :)

Comment: One should attempt to provide a domain-oriented abstraction to the consumer of just about anything.  While the notion domain may vary based on who is doing the consuming (the very next bench or a more distant consumer), a class provides for abstraction, and an array doesn't.  For example, balance, credit, and debit are domain abstractions, whereas integer, string, array are much less so.  And the abstraction mechanism of class supports substitution and maintenance as Supericy says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What benefits do you get by using a given implementation?

you can easily augument UserCollection with additional behaviour, like reacting whenever a new user is added or removed (e.g. observer pattern). using arrays, one would have to scatter such logic all over the place, while using a class you can put this logic just in one place and control it there. it is also more testable.

you can also include some invariants checking code making sure UserCollection concept always adheres to domain constraints.

even if there seem to be no immediate need for constraints or additional behaviour, these may come up later in the project life and it would be somewhat difficult to implement them in code base that wasn't designed for extensibility.